# Regex: Match all characters in between an underscore and a period

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of file names in which I need to extract their dates.  The file names look like:

```
['1 120836_1_20210101.csv',
 '1 120836_1_20210108.csv',
 '1 120836_20210101.csv',
 '1 120836_20210108.csv',
 '10 120836_1_20210312.csv',
 '10 120836_20210312.csv',
 '11 120836_1_20210319.csv',
 '11 120836_20210319.csv',
 '12 120836_1_20210326.csv',
 ...
]
```

As an example, I would need to extract `20210101` from the first item in the list above.

Here is my code but it is not working - I'm not totally familiar with regex.

```
import re
dates = []
for file in files:
    dates.extend(re.findall("(?<=_)\d{}(?=\d*\.)", file))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't that far off, but there were a few issues:

- you extend `dates` by the result of the `.findall`, but you only expect to find one and are constructing all of `dates`, so that would be a lot simpler with a `re.search` in a list comprehension
- your regex has a few unneeded complications (and some bugs)

This is what you were after:

```
import re

files = [
    '1 120836_1_20210101.csv',
    '1 120836_1_20210108.csv',
    '1 120836_20210101.csv',
    '1 120836_20210108.csv',
    '10 120836_1_20210312.csv',
    '10 120836_20210312.csv',
    '11 120836_1_20210319.csv',
    '11 120836_20210319.csv',
    '12 120836_1_20210326.csv'
]

dates = [re.search(r"(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)", fn).group(0) for fn in files]

print(dates)
```

Output:

```
['20210101', '20210108', '20210101', '20210108', '20210312', '20210312', '20210319', '20210319', '20210326']
```

It keeps the lookbehind for an underscore, and changes the lookahead to look for a period. It just matches all digits (at least one, with `+`) in between the two.

Note that the `r` in front of the string avoids having to double up the backslashes in the regex, the backslashes in `\d` and `\.` are still required to indicate a digit and a literal period.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, please click the checkmark next to the answer (once you can), so the question no longer appears unanswered.